# How to add a $variable to a onclick="location.href='

Tags: php, html, button

Hi i need help because this is not working:
I just wanted to open websites with buttons but in a search box.....

```
<html>
<body>
    <form>
        <input type=button onClick=window.open("action.php","demo","width=550,height=300,left=150,top=200,toolbar=0,status=0,"); value="Öffne">
    </form>
    <form method="post" action="action.php">Suche: <input name="suche" type="text"><br>
        <input type="submit" value="OK">
    </form>
</body>
</html>


<php
$user = $_POST['suche'];
$seite = 'www.google.de/#q=';
$ziel=$seite.$user;



<form>
      <input type=button onclick="location.href='https://www.google.de/#q=<?php echo $seite; ?>'" value='Website'>
      <input type=button onClick="self.close();" value="Close this window">
</form>
```

Comment: I didn't get the issue. May you explain in more details what are you tring to achieve and what you have done so far?

Comment: Sry for my bad explanation... I wrote down my recent question and what I have done so far as an answer at the bottom of this topic, thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have more quotes missing on html tag attr and also php closing tags try

```
<html>
<body>
<form>
<input type="button" onClick='window.open("action.php","demo","width=550,height=300,left=150,top=200,toolbar=0,status=0,");' value="Öffne">
</form>
<form method="post" action="action.php">Suche: <input name="suche" type="text"><br>
     <input type="submit" value="OK">
</form>
</body>
</html>
<?php
$user = $_POST['suche'];
$seite = 'www.google.de/#q=';
$ziel=$seite.$user;
?>
<form>
<input type="button" onclick="location.href='https://www.google.de/#q=<?php echo $seite; ?>'" value='Website'>
<input type="button" onClick="self.close();" value="Close this window">
</form>
```

Comment: please upvote or accept as an answer you found helpful

Comment: ok, I accepted the answer thanks for your help, but i have another question, I would be very thankful if you could help me...

Comment: I wrote down my question as an answer here at the bottom of this topic, if you can look please... :)

Answer (score 1):

Now I have a last question, I want to put both files index.html and action.php in one file.   So if I go on Index.html i just have to enter my value for 'suche' and klick on submit button ('ok') to save the value of 'name' into '$input' and then klick on one of the buttons google,proxer,.... to search on that websites.
(maybe if it is possible I can merge the submit btton ('OK') and the buttons (google,proxer,...) to make it cleaner)

For example the link for  google + $input would be: $seite_google.$input;

My code now looks like:

For index.php:

```
 <?php
   $input = $_POST['suche'];
    $seite_google = 'https://www.google.de/#q=';
    $seite_myanimelist = 'http://myanimelist.net/anime.php?q=';
    $seite_anisearch = 'http://de.anisearch.com/anime/index/?char=all&text=';
    $seite_proxer = 'http://proxer.me/search?name=';
    ?>
    <form>
    <input type="button" onclick="location.href='<?php echo $seite_google.$input; ?>'" value='Google Suche'>
    <input type="button" onclick="location.href='<?php echo $seite_myanimelist.$input; ?>'" value='MyAnimeList'>
    <input type="button" onclick="location.href='<?php echo $seite_anisearch.$input; ?>&q=true'" value='AniSearch'>
    <input type="button" onclick="location.href='<?php echo $seite_proxer.$input; ?>&sprache=alle&typ=all&genre=&nogenre=&sort=name&length=&length-limit=down#search'" value='Proxer'>
    </form>

    <html>
    <body>
    <form method="post" action="">Suche: <input name="suche" type="text"><br>
         <input type="submit" value="OK" name="submit">
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: so what you have problem

Comment: The code is working without problems. Now I want to merge index.html and action.php in one file (html or php), so that index.html doesn´t have to open action.php.

Comment: Man it is working, but is it possible to show both forms on one page and instead of the one submit button one have just to enter the text in the textlabel ('suche') and klick on one of the 4 buttons to start the search (for example on google) ?

Comment: hmm it does not work, I removed the if line and the else line but it just shows the first form with one button (not the one with 4 buttons)?

Comment: :D its workinggggggg... The very last question is can I delete the submit button ('OK') and use the other buttons to get the value of  name="suche" into $input ? Thanks man :)

Comment: Hmm I don´t have experience with javascript, is it easy and some lines of code for my example, or more complex?

Comment: please use above code if you make it difficult then you need more reading on google so keep it simple

Comment: I´m using the code above it is very simple and cool thank you. And okay then I will use the normal submit button...  Can I thank you in any form on this website?